# Find the first top nearest <h3> element

Tags: jquery

I need to select the `<h3>` element from the inner checkbox. I couldn't find any `jquery` selector to do it. how can I do this?

```
<h3 id="row_3">Date</h3>
<!-- 2 second-->
<div class='container'>
   <p>  
        <input type="checkbox" checked class="mathOperator"  />              
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a combination of [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(this).closest(".container").prev("h3");   // h3
```

Not sure why you wanna do when you have an `id`:

```
$("#row_3");                                // h3
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".mathOperator").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest(".container").prev("h3").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="row_3">Date</h3>
<!-- 2 second-->
<div class='container'>
  <p>  
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="mathOperator" />              
  </p>
</div>
```

Just on a side note, never duplicate the `id`s.

Comment: to make it simple I just copy a sample of the code. your first answer was perfect. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prev()` in jquery.

```
$('.mathOperator').closest('.container').prev('h3');
```

Comment: How is it different from mine? Plus no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I didn't see your post. Sounds like you post few sec before me

Comment: Sure, that's fine. But please always give some info when you post. Don't post incomplete answers. Don't do FGITW.

Answer (score 1):

With `.prev()` as other answer already have but this is another way to get it:

```js
$(function() {
  var el = $(".container:has(.mathOperator:checked)").prev("h3")[0];
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="row_3">Date</h3>
<!-- 2 second-->
<div class='container'>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="mathOperator" />
  </p>
</div>
```